# Sqldatareader optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, dapper, sqldatareader

I have a datareader that is getting results from my stored procedure. The stored procedure depending on certain values such as ("ismarried" = true) returns 10 coulmns but if ("ismarried" = false) it returns only 5 columns.

In my asp.net page my datareader is expecting 10 columns no matter what and wanted to know if there was a way in my asp.net c# code to have optional parameters. I do know you can use 
ISNULL("Column", '') in SQL but instead of doing that i was hoping there was a way to maybe tell my datareader that these 5 parameters might not always exist.

Thanks

Comment: If it's expecting 10 columns then you have to give it 10 columns. "I know 1+1=2 but I want it to =3!"

Comment: Nathan obviously you are incapable of thinking outside of your box according to the other responses looks like there are possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell how many columns that the stored procedure returned by using the [`FieldCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.fieldcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.  If it returns 5 or 10 your code can react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create the query dynamically. I use string builder to concatenate the query, if a value arrive with null or empty then in the code that parameter is not added and in the where the condition is not added either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the columns returned and then mapping based of the count of fields etc, a cleaner solution would be to create a class, let's say Person like so...

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
    //etc...
}
```

Then, you can use [`dapper`](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) to return your result...

```
var people = cnn.Query<Person>("spName", 
                     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

dapper will map the fields to your class property, and ignore any missing fields. Be aware that the property names will need to match the field names from the database. This will cut down on any logic check and having to map each property by hand to the field returned.